# Oracle Apex - Cards Column

Tags: oracle-apex

In the mobile version, the card appears all in a single column but I want it to be in 2 column. Any ideas to solve this problem?

[1 COLUMN MOBILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3a4N.png)

[2 COLUMN MOBILE HOW I WANT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqFDp.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Cards region type you can experiment with this CSS:

```
.a-CardView-items--grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill,minmax(var(--a-cv-item-width,320px),1fr));
}
```

That specifies a minimum and maximum width for the cards, so you want to try reducing the minimum by adding inline CSS something like:

```
.a-CardView-items--grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill,minmax(160px,1fr));
}
```

That changes the minimum width to 160px, so you should get 2 cards side by side as long as the device width exceeds 320px (approx).  You would want to wrap this in a media query so that it only affects smaller devices e.g.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
    .a-CardView-items--grid {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill,minmax(160px,1fr));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Tony, the change is reflected in the mobile version with 2 columns, but before you saw 4 columns in the desktop version and now you see 8 columns. How could we keep it to be 4 columns without affecting the 2 columns in the mobile version?

Comment: Hi Tony, the solution was: .a-CardView-items--grid {
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto);
} and @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
    .a-CardView-items--grid {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill,minmax(160px,1fr));
    }
}